# General findings about Galois groups

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, big-list

To get a better feeling for Galois groups I'd like to know some general cases that allow to tell a Galois group from a polynomial and vice versa.

The most simple example I came about is

> $P(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ **splits** over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff its Galois group
>   is **trivial**.

I'm looking for other "simple" properties $\mathcal{P}$ of polynomials and properties $\mathcal{G}$ of groups for which it holds:

> $P(x)$ is $\mathcal{P}$ iff its Galois group
>   is $\mathcal{G}$.

Especially:

- For which polynomials is the Galois group a full [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) group?
- For which polynomials is the Galois group an [alternating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) group?
- For which polynomials is the Galois group a [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) group?
- Which general property do the Galois groups of the polynomials $X^n - 1$ have?
- Which general property do the Galois groups of [cyclotomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) polynomials have?

Comment: Read chapter 4 in this excellent, nice book: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FTe6.pdf

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks a lot. On p. 93 I found this proposition: 
**Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial of prime degree
$p$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. If $f$ splits in $\mathbb{C}$ and has exactly two nonreal roots, then $G(f) = S_p$.** That's great. What I don't understand is: Doesn't **every** polynomial split in $\mathbb{C}$? Why is it explicitely mentioned? Can you help me?

Comment: I think this is only a slightly poor redaction of the question. That "if" there surely applies only to the part that says "If...it has **exactly** two non-real roots", but I already asked J.S. Milne directly (by e-mail) and I hope he answers in the near future.

Comment: This is J.S. Milne's answer: "I hadn't proved the fundamental theorem of algebra at the time...
Regards,
James Milne" . Thus, this sound logical, though the fact is so well known that may be a little note about this would have been appropriate. Matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @DonAntonio: thanks to you and J.S.Milne for your efforts. Yes, this sounds logical, now I feel better.

Comment: By the way, the splitting field of $f(x)$ is inseparable if and only if $f(x)$ can be written as $g(x^p)$ for some $g$.

Comment: More generally, the splitting field of $f$ is separable if $\langle f, d(f) \rangle = 1$.