# Can Abel-Ruffini be "seen" by looking at the graphs of polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, roots

The [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) states that

> there is no algebraic solution – that is, solution in radicals
>   – to the general polynomial equations of degree five or higher
>   with arbitrary coefficients.

The standard proof of this uses Galois theory and is almost purely algebraic, uses abstract permutations, and thus is not very visual.

I wonder, if the fact that polynomials of degree five or higher have no general solution in radicals can somehow be *seen* by looking at the graphs of the polynomials:

> Which visual properties do graphs of polynomials of degree five or
>   higer have (if any) that are somehow "responsible" for the fact of not
>   having radical solutions and that graphs of polynomials of degree less
>   than five **don't** have?

Two sorts of graphs might be considered;

- the function graphs $P:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sending $x$ to $P(x)$

[image] $P(x) = x^5 -4x^3 + 3x$

- the zero curves in the complex plane with [$\operatorname{Re}(P(z)) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961884/a-visually-guided-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra) and [$\operatorname{Im}(P(z)) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961884/a-visually-guided-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra)

[image] $P(x) = x^5 -2x^3 -x^2+ 3x$

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this question has a "yes" answer, and it would be hard to _prove_ the answer is "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the graphs of polynomial functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ is concerned, the answer is negative. In fact, we can solve by radicals every polynomial equation of the typ $x^3+x=a$, where $a$ is an algebraic number, but we *cannot* solve by radicals most equations of the form $x^5+x=a$. However, their graphs are very similar visualy. Just translate up or down the graphs of $x^3+x$ and of $x^5+x$ respectively. And they look like this:

[image]
[image]

In the complex version, I don't know the answer, but I would be very much surprised if it turned out to be affirmative.

Comment: Even if the answer is negative, I find it interesting: That there can be so profound and intricate differences between two seemingly very similar objects.

Comment: Maybe you want to play around with [$x^5 + x = a$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/il8xptsv37) compared to [$x^3 + x = a$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wrsnwgjbe6). (You are right: there are no obvious differences between the two.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial "yes" answer:

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $p$ for an odd prime $p$, and if $f(x)$ has exactly two nonreal roots (which is to say it has $p-2$ real roots, which you can "see" on the graph), then the Galois group (of the splitting field of) $f$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_p$. In particular, if $p > 3$, then this group isn't solvable, so you can't solve your polynomial using radicals.

To see this, just note that:

1. Complex conjugation will be a transposition in the Galois group (as it transposes the two nonreal roots and fixes the rest.
2. The Galois group acts transitively on the roots. A transitive subgroup of $S_n$ has order divisible by $n$; in this case it has order divisible by $p$ and thus must contain a $p$-cycle.
3. $S_p$ is generated by any $p$-cycle and any transposition.

Comment: This answer thrills me! Will delve deeper into it. (Only yesterday I got a hint to your first statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960475/general-findings-about-galois-groups)